# A library to make a polygon in a graph

Tags: javascript, graph

I am trying to create a graph like this https://snipboard.io/gC25HV.jpg and I was thinking of creating polygons in the graph to achieve this. Is there any library that I can use to get this result?

Comment: You can do this with a plain `canvas`. Check this example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp

Comment: I was thinking about doing this. But I'm not yet so familiar with canvas and I needed this soon so I was hoping maybe there's a library for this @RAllen

Comment: Your char looks quite custom, and I'm not sure that it will be easy to find a ready-to-use chart lib that can do what you need. For example, https://www.chartjs.org/ is quite popular, but I don't think it has such a kind of chart.